# How can I keep checking every 30 seconds on multiple processes if alive python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have program that is running 2 process in parallel. After processes are launched, I am trying to check every 30 seconds if processes are still alive. Below is my pseudo code. Both processes takes between 5-10 minutes. I checked both processes ran successfully but while processes are alive it is not getting into while loop. When it is while loop, processes are not alive anymore

```
processes=list()
proc_1 = Process(target=target1)
proc_1.start()
processes.append(proc_1)

proc_2 = Process(target=target2)
proc_2.start()
processes.append(proc_2)

for process in processes:
   process.join()

elapsed_time = 0
process_timeout = 120 # seconds
while elapsed_time < process_timeout:
       is_any_process_alive = proc_1.is_alive() or proc_2.is_alive()
       if is_any_process_alive:
          time.sleep(30)
          elapsed_time += 30
       else:
          break
```

Comment: "but somehow program is not checking every 30 seconds" how are you determining this?

Comment: In logs. I added print statements , after join() statement that return true for process is alive and inside while loop it returns false and thus It goes into else.

Comment: A few clarifications would help: 
Why aren't `proc_1` or `proc_2` added to the `processes` list? 
The `for process in processes` loop should never do anything in this case.
Why is `elapsed_time` incremented by 20 instead of 30 after `time.sleep(30)`?

Comment: missed adding append while copying code here for processes. corrected elapsed time value (it was from pervious testing i was doing).

Comment: I got it working, I should not use join() in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
for process in processes:
   process.join()
```

you are waiting for your two processes to finish before continuing on to your loop. Only after both are finished do you attempt to enter the `while` loop, but then immediately `break` as both have already finished.

`join` should be used when you need to make sure a process has finished before moving on, such as requiring that a file has been written or a computation has completed. A common tripping point on what qualifies on "computation completed" is that if you are expecting data over a `Queue`, the underlaying pipe may block if the buffer is full, so you should `.get` all expected data from that queue before you attempt to `join` as the process may still be blocking on `.put`. (TLDR) Don't wait for the process to be done before trying to get the output, as it sometimes can't finish until the output is received.

It is also notable that unless you specify `daemon=True` for a process, it will attempt to `.join` at the end of the main script as part of cleanup. If you **did** specify `daemon=True`, instead `.terminate` will be called to kill the process right away when the main process is finished. There are some instances where the interpreter shuts down unexpectedly where orphan processes can continue to live past the parent, but that's generally when extension libraries have exceptions outside of python (like a segfault)